# Passing string as an argument in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

On a fairly regular basis I want to pass in strings that function as arguments in code. For context, I often want a section where I can pass in filtering criteria or assumptions that then flow through my analysis, plots, etc. to make it more interactive.

A simple example is below. I've seen the eval/parse solution, but it seems like that makes code chunks unreadable. Is there a better/cleaner/shorter way to do this?

```
column.names <- c("group1", "group2") #two column names I want to be able to toggle between for grouping
select.column <- group.options[1] #Select the column for grouping

DataTable.summary <- 
  DataTable %>% 
  group_by(select.column) %>% #How do I pass that selection in here? 
  summarize(avg.price = mean(SALES.PRICE))
```

Comment: First, you need to make this reproducible: `Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'city.filtered' not found`. It's also unclear what you mean by "group1" being some sort of selection. Generally a selection criterion will be a logical result.

Comment: It is not so simple creating function with dplyr. You need to read about these things: tidyeval, rlang, !! operator, enquo...But it is a good question. Try updating your tags with some of the things I have written.

Comment: This link explains everything [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#quoting). Go to the section with Quoting to see an example.

Comment: Also this question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011988/supplying-multiple-groups-of-variables-to-a-function-for-dplyr-arguments-in-the

Comment: This might be useful too https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470372/786542

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is just a copy-paste from the tidyverse website: link:(https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#programming-recipes).

```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {
  group_var <- enquo(group_var)
  print(group_var)
  df %>%
    group_by(!! group_var) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}
my_summarise(df, g1)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^g1
#> env:  global
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      g1     a
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  2.5 
#> 2     2  3.33
```

But I think i illustrates your problem. I think what you really want to do is like the code above, i.e. create a function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `group_by_` function for the example in your question:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(group1 = letters[1:4], group2 = LETTERS[1:4], value = 1:4)
select.colums <- c("group1", "group2")

x %>% group_by_(select.colums[2]) %>% summarize(avg = mean(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  group2   avg
#  <fct>  <dbl>
# 1 A          1
# 2 B          2
# 3 C          3
# 4 D          4
```

The `*_` family functions in dplyr might also offer a more general solution you are after, although the dplyr documentation says they are deprecated (`?group_by_`) and might disappear at some point. An analogous expression to the above solution using the tidy evaluation syntax seems to be:

```
x %>% group_by(!!sym(select.colums[2])) %>% summarize(avg = mean(value))
```

And for several columns:

```
x %>% group_by(!!!syms(select.colums)) %>% summarize(avg = mean(value))
```

This creates a [symbol out of a string](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.2.2/topics/sym) that is evaluated by dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `group_by_at()`. It supports both single strings or character vectors:

```
nms <- c("cyl", "am")

mtcars %>% group_by_at(nms)
```