# How to pass a list of bare elements to a tidyeval plot function that accepts bare elements to purrr map

Tags: r, purrr, tidyeval

Given the following type of function:

```
library(tidyverse)

make_plot <- function(var) {
  quo_var <- enquo(var)
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = !!quo_var, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()
}
```

I would like to call this on various columns of a data.frame like this:

```
make_plot(hp)
make_plot(am)
...
```

But to keep the code DRY, I would like to use `purrr::map` or `purrr::walk`, but the following does not work:

```
list(hp, am) %>%
  map(make_plot)
```

I have also tried `list("hp", "am") %>% map(make_plot(sym(.))` which also does not work. What is the correct approach here for using a list of strings or variables?

Comment: You need `alist()` instead of `list()`. See also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834499/786542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `quote` to avoid the early evaluation

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
list(quote(hp), quote(am)) %>% 
      map(make_plot)
```

---

Or another option is to pass it as list of `quosure` (`quos`)

```
quos(hp, am) %>%
    map(make_plot)
```

-last plot

[image]

---

To make the `~ .x` work, do an evaluation with `!!`

```
quos(hp, am) %>%
            walk(~ print(make_plot(!! .x)))
```

Comment: Do you know why `quos(hp, am) %>%
  walk(~ print(make_plot(.)))` fails?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  You can use `!!`.  updated the post (to evaluate the `.x` instead of directly parsing the literal .x